# SaltStack : is it possible to apply states on the master and if so, how?

Tags: salt-stack

I am a total beginner with SaltStack but I have managed to setup some states on a machine and run them on a minion.

What I have right now is a Debian machine setup with salt-master as well as another Debian setup as salt-minion.

Since I am using the salt-master also as a development machine, I would like to know if I can somehow apply the states on the master itself as well. And if so, how?

Is there a command I can run to apply the states on the master? (so far I was unable to find it)

Should I install salt-minion on the same machine as well to be able to do this and simply register the same machine as a minion on itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Since I am using the salt-master also as a development machine, I would like to know if I can somehow apply the states on the master itself as well. And if so, how?

You can do that by following the following steps:

1. Install salt-minion on your development machine
2. Edit /etc/salt/minion to point to your master (vi /etc/salt/minion and change the following : master: salt -> master: 127.0.0.1)

   - (optional) Edit /etc/salt/minion_id to something that is meaningful to you
3. Start up your salt-minion
4. Use salt-key to accept your minion's key
5. Use your salt-master to control your minion as if it were any other salt-minion

> Is there a command I can run to apply the states on the master?

The salt-master doesn't really run the the state files, the salt-minions do. If you followed the above steps then you can target your salt-master to run highstate with the following command:

```
salt 'the_value_of_/etc/salt/minion_id' state.highstate
```

> Should I install salt-minion on the same machine as well to be able to do this and simply register the same machine as a minion on itself?

Yup. I think you have an idea as to what you need to do and just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: The numbering of you list is messed up. In the markup you have a "3.5" step, but that's incorrect markup. Also, I think 4, 5 , and 6 were meant to be one item, weren't they? Or maybe 5 and 6 are one item, but part of 5 got appended to 4. Can you fix it so that it reads like you intend it to read?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the heads up @BryanOakley

Comment: Even this setup is in poor control. E.g. if you want to execute code between the highstate.   salt.state.event + reactor + your execution code is the current way to do it.  You can put a state.event inside highstate, give it a tag, while the reactor will check the tag and execute the reaction given.

Comment: If you have already installed the Master on your development machine, then installing the minion is not needed. But you have to restart the minion service/daemon after (~3.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am new to salt, too, and the question of whether to run minion on the master is quite straightforward but I had to do a surprising amount of searching to confirm.

Answer (score 8):

### Install both Minion and Master on single node

I call such node **Master Minion**. No steps provided - you already know it based on the question.

Some conceptual info instead:

- In short, Master never applies states. Instead, it triggers Minions (the local Master Minion in this case).
- Salt Minion and Master are two separate services with **independent runtime & configuration**.
- While instances use common software, runtime **talk over the network** (location-independent).
- If you can apply states on remote Minion, **the same mechanism** will be used for local Minion one as well.

---

### Additional info

There are two ways to apply states:

- Master-side [`salt`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/ref/cli/salt.html) command to **"push"** states to multiple remote minions.

  ```
  rpm -qf $(which salt)
  salt-master-2015.5.3-4.fc22.noarch
  ```
- Minion-side [`salt-call`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/ref/cli/salt-call.html) command to **"pull"** states on single local minion.

  ```
  rpm -qf $(which salt-call)
  salt-minion-2015.5.3-4.fc22.noarch
  ```

**Until more than one minion is involved**, it's better to use `salt-call` for the same effect:

```
salt-call state.highstate
```

Minion-side `salt-call` provides advantages especially for testing, isolation, troubleshooting:

- It makes network issues (if any) more obvious.
- It safely applies states only on single local minion (no way to specify more than one).
- It shows debug output directly in the local terminal:

  ```
  salt-call -l debug test.ping
  ```

The last point, `salt-call`[`--local`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html#salt-call) can also be used in [**masterless setup**](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html) using **no network**.

Answer (score 4):

Now it's near end of 2015. Let's review some more possibilities to salt master self-control:

1. Install a minion aside with salt master on the same box

This one has been widely discussed as above two answers.

2. Use salt-ssh + salt-run state.orchestrate

Setup steps:

Step 1: install salt-ssh

Step 2: modify roster file (e.g. /etc/salt/roster in CentOS 6). The default installation already provide you some example. Since you probably ssh into salt master, of course username / password / private key setup should not be a problem for you. For example to control salt master vagrant box, this sample should do:

```
localhost:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  user: vagrant
  passwd: vagrant
  sudo: True
```

Now, steal from [official tutorial](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt5.html#orchestrate-runner) with a little bit twist:

```
# /srv/salt/orch/cleanfoo.sls
cmd.run:
  salt.function:
    - tgt: 'localhost'
    - ssh: 'true'
    - arg:
      - touch /tmp/test.txt
```

And run it with:

```
salt-run state.orchestrate orch.cleanfoo
```

Check your salt master vagrant box /tmp directory if test.txt file is there.

This approach should also work for state. Either way you need to install something. I prefer the second way since in general, calling salt master self control (to provision some work) is just a step before I actually call minion to process other state(s).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run a state file on a master without a local minion:

foo.sls:

```
/etc/foo.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://files/foo.conf
    - mode: 0600
```

To apply it, run `salt-run state.orchestrate foo`.

See https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/orchestrate/orchestrate_runner.html#running-states-on-the-master-without-a-minion